# GeoGraphics Question

Tags: graphics, geographics

I have the new and  I have the following (simple) questions:

1. I want to align the label (example Netherlands with flag) to be drawn at the graphics boundaries.
2. Make an arrows between the label and the center of the capital city (example Netherlands)?
3. Draw a rectangle around the drawing?
4. To mark every bording Country with a different color?

--

```
co = CountryData["Germany", "BorderingCountries"]
z[x_] := Reverse[CityData[CountryData[x, "CapitalCity"], "Coordinates"]] 
a[c_] := Inset[ Grid[{{c, SpanFromLeft}, {"Pop.", 
  Row[{Round[CountryData[c, "Population"]/10^6], 
    " mil."}]}, {"Flag", 
  Show[CountryData[c, "FlagImage"], ImageSize -> 30]}}, 
BaseStyle -> Directive[Small, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
Background -> White, Frame -> All], z[c]];
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightBlue, 
CountryData[#, "Polygon"] & /@ co, Black, a /@ co}, 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]